# Stored procedure, storing results in another table before returning to client

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

A stored procedure is using below query to fetch and return results to client.

```
select 
    @Lid, *         
from 
    CurrentProductSet cps 
where 
    cps.State = @state
    and cps.ProductName in (select gbb.ProductName 
                            from HMCGoodBetterBest gbb 
                            where gbb.HMC_Hospital = @hospital 
                              and gbb.HMC_Extras = @extra);
```

Can you please guide me how I can store these results in anther table for further use before returning them to client. Just don't want to fetch data twice or use a table variable. I have created another table '`Temp_CurrentProductSet`'.

**Edit:**

I tried using `into` clause trying below code but I get this error:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Code:

```
select 
    @Lid, * 
into 
    Temp_CurrentProductSet
from 
    CurrentProductSet cps 
where 
    cps.State = @state
    and cps.ProductName in (select gbb.ProductName 
                            from HMCGoodBetterBest gbb 
                            where gbb.HMC_Hospital = @hospital 
                              and gbb.HMC_Extras = @extra);
```

Comment: Your above query is storing the results in a table, `Temp_CurrentProductSet`.  `SELECT INTO` does just that.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If using a table for this, just be wary of concurrency etc. Unless you add code the data will not be deleted from the table afterwards, and unless you do something very tricky, two different connections people running the same stored proc will simply use the same table, providing unexpected results. I suggest you provide some more background on why you want to do this. Is there a performance problem?

Comment: Use output Clause in insert to show results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**You need to use output clause**

insert into Temp_CurrentProductSet output Inserted.*
select 
@Lid, *         
from 
CurrentProductSet cps 
where 
cps.State = @state
and cps.ProductName in (select gbb.ProductName 
                        from HMCGoodBetterBest gbb 
                        where gbb.HMC_Hospital = @hospital 
                          and gbb.HMC_Extras = @extra);
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to your problem is in the error:

```
An object or column name is missing or empty.
```

You need to define a column name for your `@Lid` field, something like:

```
select @Lid as Lid, * 
    into Temp_CurrentProductSet
    from ...
```

Do realize, using `SELECT INTO` will create a new table.  If you are trying to insert the values into an existing table, you need to use `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

Comment: thanks, but Insert into will not return, I want to insert and Select to send to client as well.

Comment: Um, not understanding?  This creates a new table (not a temp one, a real one), then later in your stored procedure you can `select` from that table?

Answer (score 1):

As error suggests, you need to define alias name for each column name.

Try this instead,

```
insert into Temp_CurrentProductSet
select @Lid, *      
    from CurrentProductSet cps 
    where cps.State=@state
    and 
    cps.ProductName in (select gbb.ProductName from HMCGoodBetterBest gbb where gbb.HMC_Hospital=@hospital and gbb.HMC_Extras=@extra);
```

Comment: thanks, I did it but it still not resolve issue. Insert into will insert but not send to client, I need to do both things.